# running sum on group by

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have this query

```
SELECT  NAME, OTHER_NAME, COUNT(NAME)
FROM ETHNICITY
GROUP BY NAME,OTHER_NAME
```

and I would like to add a running sum on `other_name` or `name` in that column.

For instance, if there is 3x african american and 2x name= "other" and other_name = "jewish"
I want to give it 3 and 2 as the counts and sum them up as it traverses

Any ideas how I can augment this to add that?  Thanks.

Comment: name can't be, but other_name can

Comment: Then why are you using COUNT(NAME)? It's the same as COUNT(*). Did you actually mean COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)?

Comment: running sum on what field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a running sum is easily done with the `sum() ... over()` window function:

```
select  name
,       other_name
,       name_count
,       sum(name_count) over(
            order by name, other_name) as running
from    (
        select  name
        ,       other_name
        ,       count(name) as name_count
        from    ethnicity
        group by 
                name
        ,       other_name
        order by
                name
        ,       other_name
        ) subqueryalias
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/500aa/5/0)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do this using a subquery:

```
select t.name, t.other_name, t.cnt,
       sum(cnt) over (order by name) as cumecnt
from (SELECT  NAME, OTHER_NAME, COUNT(NAME) as cnt
      FROM ETHNICITY
      GROUP BY NAME,OTHER_NAME
     ) t
```

This assumes that you want a cumulative sum of count in the order of `name`.

The order by in the analytic functions do cumulative sums.  This is standard syntax, and also supported by Postgres and SQL Server 2012.

The following might also work

```
select name, other_name, count(name) as cnt,
       sum(count(name)) over (order by name)
from ethnicity
group by name, other_name
```

I find this harder to read (the `sum(count())` is a bit jarring) and perhaps more prone to error.  I haven't tried this syntax on Oracle; it does work in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What could `order by` mean in the context of the `Sum` analytic? Isn't it just `sum(cnt) over ()`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Grouping sets, lets you aggregate totals.

Not sure this is what you're after though...

```
SELECT  NAME, OTHER_NAME, COUNT(NAME)
FROM ETHNICITY
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((NAME,OTHER_NAME), (Name), ())
```

Sorry ID10T error... the grouping sets didn't require a 2nd aggregate, the count will do it on it's own:

So this data:

```
Name   Other_Name
A       B
A       C
A       D
B       E
B       F
B       G
C       H
C       I
C       J
```

Results in

```
Name   Other_Name   CNT(Name)
A      B           1
A      C           1
A      D           1
A                  3
B      E           1
B      F           1
B      G           1
B                  3
C      H           1
C      I           1
C      J           1
C                  3
                   9
```

Comment: this is giving a "not a single group by function"

Comment: Just depends on the output you want.  Gordon's approach works for more of a running total by name as does Andomar's; mine works if you want the totals as separate records. with cumulative at end.  Not really a "running total"